# Remove all selected rows even though I'm in other page using react-table with controlled pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, server-side, react-table

Using **react-table v7**, I'm having a hard time trying to delete all rows selected even though I'm in other page using **toggleAllRowsSelected** from hook-plugin **useRowSelect**.

I'm using controlled pagination for server-side and as the documentation says, I set `autoResetSelectedRows: false` to store in the state the prop **selectedRowIds**. So when I change the page, the data changes but I can keep the **selectedRowIds** intact. It works fine when I check or uncheck one single row, but I can't figure out how to uncheck all of them, not just the rows in the current page, which is what **toggleAllRowsSelected** is doing.

I'm doing something wrong or is a bug in **toggleAllRowsSelected** callback? Is there a way to manipulate the state of react-table to change manually the **selectedRowIds** prop?

I solved it this way.. but it could cause performance issues I think... :

```
  const handleUnselectAll = () => {
    state.selectedRowIds = {};
    toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
  };
```

Documentation:

**useRowSelect**: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useRowSelect#userowselect

**Data from server-side**: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using **stateReducer** option.

```
  stateReducer: (newState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'toggleAllRowsSelected':
        return {
          ...newState,
          selectedRowIds: {},
        };

      default:
        return newState;
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#usetable